# How to apply click method on google maps Markers?? (React - Google Maps)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

I am using react and google maps to create a map with full functionality, markers, infoWindow. now i added the functionality that pop up an infowindow when click a marker by adding the listener to all markers in a loop

```
this.state.markers.forEach(marker => {
    marker.addListener('click', e => {this.openInfoWindow()})
});
```

but i have a sidebar that contains the names of locations of these markers, what is required is when clicking a list item in the sidebar, an info window pops up from the corresponding marker, i tried this but did not work

```
this.state.markers.forEach(marker => marker.click());
```

but this did not work and i have an error

> marker.click() is not a function

I am **not** using any libraries like google-map-react.

**So why it works only when the click even done by mouse but not click() method and is there a way to make it work????**

Comment: can you create a codepen for this?

Comment: https://codepen.io/dhavaljardosh/pen/oPXYWy?editors=0010 - Try to put your code on this codepen,

Comment: Could you add your render function to see how you show markers on it and have a bigger picture.

Comment: it is difficult to edit your codepen, this is because i need the list items to click so the click even is triggered on the corresponding marker  @Dhaval Jardosh

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bxdBmV

Comment: ok try to do this, share your code on github. Coz it's really difficult to answer otherwise. Solution might be very simple, just need to figure out where the problem is.

Comment: @DhavalJardosh thank you it worked after i did that

     ```new window.google.maps.event.trigger( marker, 'click' );
```

but i still have a problem that infoWindow is duplicated , the old one should be closed when a new one open

Comment: Hey @SaherElgendy, please explain in the readme of github, what your program is doing so I can get better idea of it. I got the basic understanding of it though.

Comment: @DhavalJardosh this is my second version of a project, i tried to use another logic in this one, so you can find the readme me in my first version here. https://github.com/saher-elgendy/Neighborhood-Map-React-

Comment: @DhavalJardosh the duplication of the infowWindow happen only after filteration process and dont know why???